# High Kernel CPU when running multiple python programs

Tags: python, linux, performance, multiprocessing

I developed a python program that does heavy numerical calculations. I run it on a linux machine with 32 Xeon CPUs, 64GB RAM, and Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I launch multiple python instances with different model parameters in parallel to use multiple processes without having to worry about the global interpreter lock (GIL). When I monitor the cpu utilization using `htop`, I see that all cores are used, however most of the time by kernel. Generally, the kernel time is more than twice the user time. I'm afraid that there is a lot of overhead going on on the system level, but I'm not able to find the cause for this.

**How would one reduce the high kernel CPU usage?**

Here are some observation I made:

- This effect appears independent of whether I run 10 jobs or 50. If there are fewer jobs than cores, not all cores are used, but the ones that are used still have a high CPU usage by the kernel
- I implemented the inner loop using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org), but the problem is not related to this, since removing the numba part does not resolve the problem
- I also though that it might be related to using python2 similar to the [problem mentioned in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27810561/932593) but switching from python2 to python3 did not change much
- I measured the total number of context switches performed by the OS, which is about 10000 per second. I'm not sure whether this is a large number
- I tried increasing the python time slices by setting `sys.setcheckinterval(10000)` (for python2) and `sys.setswitchinterval(10)` (for python3) but none of this helped
- I tried influencing the task scheduler by running `schedtool -B PID` but this didn't help

**Edit:**
Here is a screenshot of `htop`:
[image]

I also ran `perf record -a -g` and this is the report by `perf report -g graph`:

```
Samples: 1M of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 1114297095227                                   
-  95.25%          python3  [kernel.kallsyms]                           [k] _raw_spin_lock_irqsave   ◆
   - _raw_spin_lock_irqsave                                                                          ▒
      - 95.01% extract_buf                                                                           ▒
           extract_entropy_user                                                                      ▒
           urandom_read                                                                              ▒
           vfs_read                                                                                  ▒
           sys_read                                                                                  ▒
           system_call_fastpath                                                                      ▒
           __GI___libc_read                                                                          ▒
-   2.06%          python3  [kernel.kallsyms]                           [k] sha_transform            ▒
   - sha_transform                                                                                   ▒
      - 2.06% extract_buf                                                                            ▒
           extract_entropy_user                                                                      ▒
           urandom_read                                                                              ▒
           vfs_read                                                                                  ▒
           sys_read                                                                                  ▒
           system_call_fastpath                                                                      ▒
           __GI___libc_read                                                                          ▒
-   0.74%          python3  [kernel.kallsyms]                           [k] _mix_pool_bytes          ▒
   - _mix_pool_bytes                                                                                 ▒
      - 0.74% __mix_pool_bytes                                                                       ▒
           extract_buf                                                                               ▒
           extract_entropy_user                                                                      ▒
           urandom_read                                                                              ▒
           vfs_read                                                                                  ▒
           sys_read                                                                                  ▒
           system_call_fastpath                                                                      ▒
           __GI___libc_read                                                                          ▒
    0.44%          python3  [kernel.kallsyms]                           [k] extract_buf              ▒
    0.15%          python3  python3.4                                   [.] 0x000000000004b055       ▒
    0.10%          python3  [kernel.kallsyms]                           [k] memset                   ▒
    0.09%          python3  [kernel.kallsyms]                           [k] copy_user_generic_string ▒
    0.07%          python3  multiarray.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  [.] 0x00000000000b4134       ▒
    0.06%          python3  [kernel.kallsyms]                           [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqresto▒
    0.06%          python3  python3.4                                   [.] PyEval_EvalFrameEx
```

It seems as if most of the time is spent calling `_raw_spin_lock_irqsave`. I have no idea what this means, though.

Comment: Have you checked what else is running on the system?  The output from `top` would be interesting.

Comment: I don't have anything out of the ordinary. This is not even the computer I use for my daily work. I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Please run `perf record -a` from root (chdir to `/tmp`) and then `perf report`. It'll give you a clue what kernel is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I included the first lines of the report in the original question. It seems as if the call to `_raw_spin_lock_irqsave` dominates. I've no idea what this means, but I'll ask google.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: nah, it only means competition for a spinlock in kernel, but we don't know which spinlock. Try to call `perf record -a -g` with `-g` option, it will collect callers of `_raw_spin_lock_irqsave`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031210/linux-perf-how-to-interpret-and-find-hotspots

Comment: I ran the commands and as far as I can see the functions seem to be related to some kind of random numbers. I should say that I use random numbers heavily in my numerics. Could it be that all these kernel CPU are just calls to a random number generator?

Comment: Yes, you read `/dev/urandom` way too often. But Python should read it only during initialization of `random` module, or when you explicitly ask for it using `SystemRandom` or `os.urandom`...

Comment: Now that we have narrowed down the problem to the random numbers, I'll try to construct a minimal example demonstrating the problem and will then contact the numba/python people. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the problem exists in kernel, you should narrow down a problem using a profiler such as OProfile or [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

I.e. run `perf record -a -g` and than read profiling data saved into `perf data` using `perf report`. See also: [linux perf: how to interpret and find hotspots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13923912/2709018).

---

In your case high CPU usage is caused by competition for `/dev/urandom` -- it allows only one thread to read from it, but multiple Python processes are doing so.

Python module `random` is using it only for initialization. I.e:

```
$ strace python -c 'import random;
while True:
    random.random()'
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)     = 4
read(4, "\16\36\366\36}"..., 2500) = 2500
close(4)                                   <--- /dev/urandom is closed
```

You may also explicitly ask for `/dev/urandom` by using `os.urandom` or `SystemRandom` class. So check your code which is dealing with random numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now that I knew what I was looking for, I realized that I indeed had a bug in *my* code base where I would for some reason initialize the random number generator every time a certain base object was created. I was only able to find that part in some old code because I knew exactly what I was looking for! I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.